# awk + adding a column baed on values of another column + adding a field name in the 1 command

Tags: python, awk

I want to add a new column at the end, based on the text of another column(with an if statement), and then I want to add a new column/field name.
I am close but I am struggling with the syntax, I am using awk, but apologies its been a while since I used this. and I am wondering if I should use python/anaconda(jupyter notebook), but going with the easiest env I have available to me at the minute, awk .

This is my file:

```
$ cat file1
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5
```

Here I want, based on the text in column 4, create a new column at the end and, but I am winging this a bit, that is I got it to work.

```
  $ awk -F, '{if (substr($4,1,1)=="A")
print $0 (NR>1 ? FS substr($4,1,4) : "")
else
print $0 (NR>1 ? FS substr($4,1,2) : "")
}' file1
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SB
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
```

But here I wnat to add a field/column name at the end, which I am close, I believe.

```
   $ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{ print $0, "test"}
NR>1
{
if (substr($4,1,1)=="A")
print $0 (NR>1 ? FS substr($4,1,4) : "")
else
print $0 (NR>1 ? FS substr($4,1,2) : "")
}
' file1
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SB
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
```

What I want is this:

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SB
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
```

### EDIT1

for my ref: this is the awk I want:

```
awk -F, '{if (substr($4,1,1)=="P")
print $0 (NR>1 ? FS substr($4,5,4) : "")
else
print $0 (NR>1 ? FS substr($4,1,4) : "")
}' file1
```

outputting it to file2:

```
awk -F, '{if (substr($4,1,1)=="P")
print $0 (NR>1 ? FS substr($4,5,4) : "")
else
print $0 (NR>1 ? FS substr($4,1,4) : "")
}' file1 > file2
$
$
```

2 files, file2 has other column added:

```
$ls
file1  file2
$cat file1
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQG,row4_5
$cat file2
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SBCD
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQG,row4_5,ASDQ
```

### EDIT2 -- Correction

file 2 is what I want:

```
cat file1
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQG,row4_5



cat file2
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SBCD
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQG,row4_5,ASDQ


awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{ print $0, "test"}
NR>1 {
if (substr($4,1,1)=="P")
print $0 (NR>1 ? FS substr($4,5,4) : "")
else
print $0 (NR>1 ? FS substr($4,1,4) : "")
}
' file1
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SBCD
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
row4_1,row4_2,row4_3,PRE-ASDQG,row4_5,ASDQ
```

Comment: Your code gives correct(your expected) output to me. Can you please check if you have control M chars in your Input_file? Do a `cat -v Input_file` once and see what you get there, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The OPs code would give the output they show. There's no control-Ms, the OP is just printing each line twice, first time from the `NR>1` alone line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newlines matter. Change:

```
NR>1
{
```

to

```
NR>1 {
```

As written you have 2 independent statements equivalent to:

```
NR>1 { print }
<true condition> {
    if (whatever) print foo; else print bar
}
```

instead of what you intended:

```
NR>1 {
    if (whatever) print foo; else print bar
}
```

Having said that, try this instead of what you have:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR == 1 { x = "test" }
    NR > 1  { x = substr( $4, 1, ($4 ~ /^A/ ? 4 : 2) ) }
    { print $0, x }
' file1
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SB
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
```

Same functionality, just more concise.

Rename `x` to some mnemonic of whatever you really intend that last column to represent.

Comment: tks this works, it seems OFS is only required for this part `NR == 1 { x = "test" }`

Comment: how do I loop if statements with in this 
`NR > 1  { x = substr( $3, 1, ($3 ~ /^[A]/ ? 4 : 2) ) }`
e.g. 
if $3 ~ /^[A]/ ? 4 : elseif $3 ~ /^PRE-/ then substr($3,5,4) elseif....

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means, ask a new question as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` command that removes any carriage return if present from each line before computing value of the last column:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} 
{
   sub(/\r$/, "")
   print $0, (NR==1 ? "test" : (substr($4,1,1)=="A" ? substr($4,1,4) : substr($4,1,2)))
}' file

f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SB
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
```

Comment: tks, the sub() is not needed.
`awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
{
   print $0, (NR==1 ? "test" : (substr($4,1,1)=="A" ? substr($4,1,4) : substr($4,1,2)))
}' file1
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SB
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
`

Comment: (NR==1 ? "test" : (substr($4,1,1)=="A" ? substr($4,1,4) : substr($4,1,2)))

does this mean
for `NR==1 `
do `"test" `
else 
do `(substr($4,1,1)=="A" ? substr($4,1,4) : substr($4,1,2)) `

`? is like do and : is like else ` am i understanding right?

Comment: That is absolutely right. It is like if (NR==1) print "test"; elseif (substr($4,1,1)=="A") print substr($4,1,4); else print substr($4,1,2);`

Answer (score 1):

`awk` one-liner :

```
gawk '$++NF =(_^=!_)==NR ? "test" : substr(__=$4,_++,_^_^(__~"^A"))' FS=, OFS=,
```

|

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SB
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
```

to deal with Windows/DOS files, do this instead :

```
mawk 'BEGIN {    RS ="\r?\n"; ___ = "test"; OFS = FS = ","   
       _++  } $++NF = _==NR ? ___ : substr(__=$4,_,++_^_--^(__~"^A"))'
```

This works because the `regex` selects whether to take `2^2^1` or `2^2^0`, which works out to 4 and 2 respectively

Comment: tks, this works, what is the difference in awk and gawk ? or mawk.
don't understand your `_` or `++NF` here  `$++NF =(_^=!_)==NR ? "test" : substr(__=$4,_++,_^_^(__~"^A"))'`?
NF is last column

Comment: @HattrickNZ : `awk` is a generic term - `gawk / mawk / nawk` are diff implementations that could run `awk` code. i try to avoid using `awk` directly in my examples, since different `OS` or diff distros of `Linux` have a different `awk` set as the default one, each with its own nuisances, so I try to be specific which ones I've tested them upon and works.  treat `_` like any other user variable - unlike `perl`, `"_"` has no special meaning in `awk`. like u said, `NF` is last column at any moment, so `++NF` means i'm pre-incrementing it by one, so `$++NF = ...` is same as `$( NF += 1 ) = …`

Comment: @HattrickNZ : The only restriction about `NF` is that setting it to a negative would be a fatal error. Other than that, feel free to set it to whatever you like - even `NF = exp( 3.14159…..)` is perfectly valid (of course `awk` wouldn't be creating a fractional field for you - it would be integer truncated in reality …. unless it's like X.99999999……, then it might round up ) ….. (cont'd)

Comment: `jot 30 | gawk -d- -p- -e 'NF = exp(atan2(0,-1))' RS= FS='\n' OFS=' | '  ::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::: 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23` :::::::: `gawk`'s detailed info actually shows `NF: 23.140692632779267`

Comment: ….. then if you attempt to fudge `NF` in the `END { }` section :::::::::::::: ::::::: ::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::: ::::::: `END { OFMT = "%.17f"; print NF, ++NF, --NF, NF ^= 2 }` :::::::: prints out :::::::::::::::::::::::::: `23.14069263277926680 | 24.14069263277926680 | 23.14069263277926680 | 535.49165552476461016`  -  `awk` actually retains the floating point value of it, even when doing `++/--` …. extremely subtle difference being `gawk -M` arbitrary precision mode would performing rounding on `NF`, while any other `gawk` mode,  plus any other `awk`, does integer truncation.

Comment: @HattrickNZ : `awk` is insanely capable : :::      `in0:  988MiB 0:00:00 [2.84GiB/s] [2.84GiB/s] [============>] 100%            
     out9: 11.0 B 0:00:30 [ 365miB/s] [ 365miB/s] [ <=> ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3s}" | mawk2 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=_=""; RS="^$" } END { print NF }' )  8.24s user 15.44s system 76% cpu 30.838 total

     1 1,036,334,374` ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: only took it `30.8 secs` to split a `988 MB` file by individual bytes, with a `NF` count of 1.036 ***billion***

Answer (score 1):

`python` solution using solely standard library, let `file.csv` content be

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5
```

then

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', newline='') as infile:
    with open('fileout.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
        outfields = reader.fieldnames + ['test']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, outfields)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            row['test'] = row['f4'][:4] if row['f4'][0] == 'A' else row['f4'][:2]
            writer.writerow(row)
```

creates (or overwrite if already exist) file `fileout.csv` with followinc content

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,test
row1_1,row1_2,row1_3,SBCDE,row1_5,SB
row2_1,row2_2,row2_3,AWERF,row2_5,AWER
row3_1,row3_2,row3_3,ASDFG,row3_5,ASDF
```

Explanation: I am using `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` from [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), firstly I create two context managers (`with open`...) with newline suitable for reader and writer (see linked docs for further explanation), infile is opened for reading (default), whilst outfile for writing (`w`), I use reader for parsing infile, I concatenate its fieldnames (column names) with list holding single element `test` to get fieldnames for output file, then I output header (column names), then for each data row in input file I compute value for test using ternary operator (observe it is valueiftrue `if` condition `else` valueiffales which is different order than GNU `AWK`'s condtion`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse) and string slicing (`[:n]` means take n first character) and insert that into `row` dict, which is then written.

*(tested in Python 3.8.10)*

Comment: tks this works `Python 3.10.9`
but what is this output I get 
`21
38
40
40
`

Comment: @HattrickNZ when using interactive prompt write inform how much was written, please put my code into file named `transform.py` in same directory as `file.csv`  and then use it following way `python transform.py`